# Has anyone used ActionChains of Webdriver(python binding)?

Tags: python, webdriver

Im trying to trigger mouse over event using move_to_element in ActionChains, Couldn't get it working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try actor.py instead: https://gist.github.com/2036553 -- it lets you call the actions directly instead of storing them, then calling 'perform'.

Answer (score 13):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(drivers).move_to_element(drivers.find_element_by_id('element_id')).click().perform()
```

if you  want to select any value,

```
 menu1 = drivers.find_element_by_xpath('html/path/of/select/box')
 sub_menu0 = drivers.find_element_by_xpath('html/path/of/selected/option')
 clickon = drivers.find_element_by_xpath(path/of/option/where/you/want/to/click)
 action = ActionChains(drivers)
 action.move_to_element(menu1)
 action.move_to_element(sub_menu0)
 action.click(clickon)
 action.perform()
```

Comment: `drivers` must be just poor naming convention

Comment: @User agreed: Perhaps a better name for it would be `driver` instead of `drivers`, as the `s` implies more than one object (e.g., a list of, say, `selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver` objects versus only one).  But other than that, this answer was *extremely* helpful as many of the other hacks, including resorting to calling `click` from javascript did not work for me, but this one did.

Answer (score 8):

I've been toying with ActionChains in python today as well and realized that the double_click doesn't work only click.  So what's your code look like.  To do any action change you have to run perform.

```
 def setUp(self):
    self.webdriver = webdriver.Ie()
    self.mouse = webdriver.ActionChains(self.webdriver)
    self.webdriver.get("http://foo")

def test_webdriver(self):
    mouse = self.mouse
    wd = self.webdriver
    wd.implicitly_wait(10)
    element = wd.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@title='Create Page']")
    mouse.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Answer (score 5):

I was getting an ActionChains is not defined error until i imported actionchains from selenium. Then I was able to use actions.move_to_element() and actions.click()

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```