# How to send ESC key to close pop up window using Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

As mentioned, is there a way to send global `ESC` key to close popup(CSS MODAL Window)? I tried following but did not work:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
```

I know I can use xPath etc but issue is the site has dynamic elementIds and classnames.

Comment: What kind of popup? Alert, window or frame?

Comment: @ElRuso Modal Div

Comment: Related, see [Typing Enter/Return key using Python and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1629053/608639)

Answer (score 73):

You don't need to send keys to the element, you need to press them globally (to browser).

You can do it via Actions.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
```

You can see more info in [Webdriver API - 7.2 Action Chains](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) doc

Comment: I had to add the import of ActionChains in order to get this to work, and just used `ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()` without the `webdriver` bit in front.  Import info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26669375/6163621

Comment: you need to import first thing you are going to work with - in this example it's either webdriver or ActionChains

Answer (score 0):

This code will send the "Esc" key in the browser window:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
def sendesc(browser):
    ActionChains(browser).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
```

Comment: Could you add some human explanations of your solution, please ? that would be great : ) easier to understand

Comment: @snoobdogg it initialize an action chain that will send the "Esc" key to the window of the browser, and then run the action chain

Answer (score -2):

I code my Selenium Python scripts in the AppRobotic Personal editor, and just insert its Windows macro functionality in between Selenium actions.

```
import win32com.client
x = win32com.client.Dispatch("AppRobotic.API")
from selenium import webdriver

x.Type("{ESCAPE}")
```

Answer (score -5):

try also this it will go back to the previous driver u had

```
driver.back()
```

Comment: this is different. based on documentation `driver.back()` goes one step backward in the browser history http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.back