# How to hold "ALT" and then “Esc” key in Selenium WebDriver using python?

Tags: python, selenium, keypress

I am doing automated testing using Selenium WebDriver with Python In Internet Explorer. I have opened multiple windows in IE 11 and I closed the current window, after that second last opened window is not getting any focus so to give focus to second last window I want to click and hold on ALT button and then click on ESC button so that second last window get focus.

Basically, I need to achieve the focus on second last window.

eg:
SendKeys.SendKeys("{ALT}" + "{ESC}")

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium: How to send ESC key to close pop up window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649916/python-selenium-how-to-send-esc-key-to-close-pop-up-window)

Answer (score 1):

`ActionChains` is what you're looking for.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

combine_keys = ActionChains(driver)
combine_keys.key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).key_up(Keys.ALT).perform()
```

Comment: needs Keys to be imported:  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys