# How to close yet another chrome popup using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web, web-scraping

[image]

[Link to 
"chrome_options.add_extension(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\extension.crx')"](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c85SNCTCllVW1SJGkKZFOFKCFov-RUjZ)

Here is my code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import gmtime, strftime
from os import system
import pyperclip
import datetime
import time
import os
import sys



executable_path = r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\extension.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
time.sleep(4)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/gK6Rq0UH/")
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="footer-chart-panel"]/div[2]/span[4]""").click()
time.sleep(4)
while True:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="bottom-area"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[4]""").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    contents = pyperclip.paste()
    time.sleep(2)
    filepath = r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DATA.txt"
    time.sleep(2)
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f: # 'w' means write mode and we get the file object as f
        f.write(contents)
        time.sleep(5)
```

i tried this code, but it didn't helps

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

this code don't work too

```
driver.send_keys("Enter")
```

if i right-click on popup there is simply no action, so i cant find XPath, class id

[this is sources that (autoview) extension, i assume that this code generate this popup](https://gitlab.com/tranzium/autoview/blob/master/js/functions.js)

```
function clipboard(format, data) {
    const tmp = document.oncopy;

    document.oncopy = function clipboard_oncopy(e) {
        e.clipboardData.setData(format, data);
        e.preventDefault();
    };
    document.execCommand("copy", false, null);
    alert("Copied to Clipboard");

    document.oncopy = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Did you try sending the Escape key?
This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649916/python-selenium-how-to-send-esc-key-to-close-pop-up-window) would be helpfull in resolving your issue.

Comment: Doesnt help                                                                                                        

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`driver.switch_to_alert().accept()`

Comment: Nailed! Thank you